# How do I integrate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(t+1)}{t^2+a^2} \mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

How do I integrate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(t+1)}{t^2+a^2} \mathrm{d}t$$

Where $a$ is some parameter?

I know that the solution includes Lerch Transcendents and logs (which is what I'm trying to arrive at); however, I've tried integrating this function, but failed.

I've already tried using simplifying it using series, which yielded a bunch of integrals as follows:

$$-\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \int_0^1 \frac{t^k} {t^2+a^2} \mathrm{d}t - \frac{1}{a^2} \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \int_0^1 \frac{t^k} {t^2+\frac{1}{a^2}} \mathrm{d}t + \frac{1}{a^2} \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \int_0^1 \frac{\log(t)} {t^2+\frac{1}{a^2}} \mathrm{d}t$$

However, I don't know how I'd proceed forwards from here.

Comment: Are you familiar with dilogarithms?

Comment: Yup, I am familiar with polylogarithms. But I don't immediately see how they'd apply here.

Comment: None of the answers below have the Lerch Phi which you mentioned. I don't have justification for this, but Mathematica produced $$\bigg(\Phi(-a^{-2},2,1/2)+4a\operatorname{arccot}(a)\log(a)+\pi |a|\log(1+a^2)\bigg)\cdot \frac{1}{4a^2}$$

Comment: @K.defaoite Oh, thank you! I proved this identity this morning by pattern-matching the integral solution with the Lerch with the solutions above - but it's really nice seeing that my derivation was correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(t+1)}{t^2+a^2} \ dt\\
=& \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{t}{(t^2+a^2)(1+yt)}dy \ dt\\
=& \int_0^1 \frac1{1+a^2y^2}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{a^2y}{t^2+a^2}+ \frac{t}{t^2+a^2}-\frac{y}{1+yt}\right)dt\ dy\\
= & \ \frac\pi2 \int_0^1 \frac{ay}{1+a^2y^2}dy-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (a)}{1+a^2y^2}\ dy- \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (y)}{1+a^2y^2}\ dy\\
=& \ \frac\pi{4a}\ln(1+a^2)-\frac1a\ln (a)\tan^{-1}(a) 
-\frac i{2a}(\mathrm{Li}_2(ia)-\mathrm{Li}_2(-ia))
\end{align}

Comment: Your solution becomes negative for $a\ge 0.513899$, but should be always positive.

Comment: @gpmath. I do not see how you find that. The result is very fine and it is always positive if $a>0$. For $a=1$, $C+\frac{1}{4} \pi  \log (2)=1.46036$

Comment: Because
$\frac{i (\text{Li}_2(i a)-\text{Li}_2(-i a))}{2 a}\text{/.}\, a\to 1=-C$
but not $C$

Comment: There is still a sign error. Correct is
$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\log (t+1)}{a^2+t^2} \, dt=\frac{\pi  \log \left(a^2+1\right)}{4 a}-\frac{\log (a) \tan ^{-1}(a)}{a}\color{red}{-}\frac{i (\text{Li}_2(i a)-\text{Li}_2(-i a))}{2 a}$

Comment: @gpmath Yeah, that's correct. There is a sign error there.

Comment: I've edited the sign error out from the post, it should look good now.

Answer (score 4):

$$I(b)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(bt+1)}{t^2+a^2} \,dt$$
$$I'(b)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t}{\left(t^2+a^2\right) (b t+1)}\,dt=\frac{\pi  a b-2 \log (a b)}{2 \left(a^2 b^2+1\right)}$$
$$J=\int \frac{\pi  a b-2 \log (a b)}{2 \left(a^2 b^2+1\right)}\,db=\frac 1{2a}\int \frac{\pi  x-2 \log (x)}{x^2+1}\,dx$$
$$J=\frac 1{2a}\Bigg[\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log \left(x^2+1\right)-2 \log (x) \tan
   ^{-1}(x)+i (\text{Li}_2(-i x)-\text{Li}_2(i x)) \Bigg]$$ Go back to $b$, use the bounds to obtain what @Quanto already answered.

Comment: As someone who absolutely loves Feynman's technique, I've got to go with this gorgeous one.

Comment: @DaddyMyers Yeah, pro tip - whenever you see a difficult integral with a log, always try to differentiate to get rid of it, even if that means you have to introduce an extra parameter.

Comment: @K.defaoite And the reason why is because the derivative is rational function which makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

*Partial Answer*

By a counter integral we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t^2+a^2}dt=\frac{\pi}{2a}\ln(a^2+1)+\frac{\pi i}{a}\arctan a\tag 1$$
After some play, I got
$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t^2+a^2}dt=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t^2+a^2}dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+a^2t^2}dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{1+a^2t^2}dt+\frac{\pi i}{a}\arctan a\tag 2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ and writing the $3$-rd integral in $(2)$ by means of "Li",
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t^2+a^2}dt=\frac{\pi}{2a}\ln(a^2+1)+\frac{i}{2a}(\text{Li}_2(ai)-\text{Li}_2(-ai))-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t^2+a^2}dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+a^2t^2}dt.$$
The last two integrals can also be evaluated by Li-function. I found them. I will update my answer if I can find some simplifications.

Answer (score -3):

let's generalize your integral
$$ \mathcal{I}(b) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+b \, x)}{a^2+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \hspace{5mm} \cdots (1) $$
Using *Feynmann's Trick* we get (differentiating w.r.t *b*)
\begin{align*} 
\mathcal{I}'(b) &= \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(1+b\,x) \, (x^2 + a^2)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{1+a^2 \, b^2} \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{-b}{1+bx} + \frac{x}{x^2+a^2} + \frac{a^2 b}{x^2 + a^2} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{1+a^2 \, b^2} \left( - \ln(1+b \, x) + \frac{1}{2} \, \ln(x^2+a^2) + ab \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{a} \right) \right) \bigg{|}_0^\infty \\
&= \frac{1}{1+a^2 \, b^2} \left( \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{1+b x} \right)\bigg{|}_0^\infty + \frac{a b \pi}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1+a^2 \, b^2} \left( - \ln(a) + \frac{a b \pi}{2} \right)
\end{align*}

Now we have
$$ \mathcal{I}'(b) = \frac{1}{1+a^2 \, b^2} \left( - \ln(a) + \frac{a b \pi}{2} 
\right) \hspace{5mm} \cdots (2)$$

After integrating (2) w.r.t *b* we get
$$ \mathcal{I}(b) = \frac{- \ln(a)}{a} \, \tan^{-1}(a b) + \frac{\pi}{4a} \ln(1 + a^2 b^2) + \mathrm{C} \hspace{5mm} \cdots (3) $$

Notice in (1) $$ \mathcal{I}(0) = 0 $$

So putting $b = 0$ in (3) we get

$$ \mathcal{I}(0) = 0 = 0 + 0 + \mathrm{C} \implies \mathrm{C} = 0 $$

So from (3)
$$ \mathcal{I}(b) = \frac{- \ln(a)}{a} \, \tan^{-1}(a b) + \frac{\pi}{4a} \ln(1 + a^2 b^2) \hspace{5mm} \cdots (4) $$

Now putting $b = 1$ in (4) we get desired answer

$$ \boxed{ \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x)}{a^2 + x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{- \ln(a)}{a} \, \tan^{-1}(a) + \frac{\pi}{4a} \ln(1 + a^2) }$$

Comment: Dear downvoters, why you downvoted my answer? Yeah, I admit that I forgot to type **derivative** symbol but you could have edited it.

Comment: I believe it's incorrect, check the other replies and you'll see why.

Comment: The downvotes are because your answer is incorrect. With $a=3$, numerical integration yields $0.830433$ whereas your answer gives $0.145410$.

Comment: @K.defaoite yeah! But I don't know why it is incorrect, here on Math.SE I have seen many integrations that were solved using Feynmann Technique. Sorry I'm going to learn numerical integration soon any recommendations? And thank you for telling me why my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @LuckyChouhan There is nothing wrong with Feynman's technique. Your answer is just incorrect. You must have made a mistake somewhere. I performed the numerical integration using Mathematica's `NIntegrate`.

Comment: The reason your answer is wrong is that $$\left.\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{1+bx}\right)\right\rvert_0^\infty = -\ln(a\color{red}{b})$$
Following your process from there easily gets you to the right answer. It would have been helpful if downvoters pointed this out before downvoting.

Comment: @Jacob oh yeah! Thank you, Jacob. Lemme correct it.